# Error ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied when trying to create a new user and logging in

Tags: sql, oracle

So I recently tried to create a new user on my Oracle 19C SQL Plus and granted all privileges, but it keeps showing the error ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.
Nothing is wrong with the credentials, there is something else that's causing this error repeatedly. Please help me out.
Also, I have a CDB and I converted that to PDB using the commands:

```
alter session set container=orclpdb;
startup;
show con_name;
show pdbs;
```

Comment: Did you create the new user in CDB or PDB, and which are you trying to connect to when you get the error?

Comment: @AlexPoole I created the new user in PDB and that's when I keep getting this error. I used the command : 'create user username identified by password' and granted all privileges.

Comment: "granted all privileges" is worrying, but not relevant... OK, so you created the user in the PDB, but what are you connecting to - and how? Are you just trying to do a `connect` after altering the session (which won't work, as you start a new session); or launching a new instance of SQL\*Plus with username/password on the command line 0 which case, using a different connect string that points to the PDB? Please edit your question to include the commands, particularly exactly how you're trying to connect at the new user.